# Header is not showing full width

Tags: theme-development, css

i am using bootstrap in WordPress. Header is not showing full width in WordPress. But when i test the code without WordPress it shows full width with background image. What can be the reason?

```
//my html

            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="header-container text-center background-image" style="background-image: url(<?php header_image(); ?>);">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

//css settings
.header-container{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 326px;
    }
    .background-image{
        background-size: cover;
        background-position:  center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

once you add width: 100%; 
in your header container css

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: added width:100%. but not working.